# Replacing all elements except NaN in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace all elements in array `X` except `nan` with `10.0`. Is there a one-step way to do it? I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
from  numpy import nan

X = np.array([[3.25774286e+02, 3.22008654e+02, nan, 1.85356823e+02,
        1.85356823e+02, 3.22008654e+02, nan, 3.22008654e+02]])
```

The expected output is

```
X = array([[10.0, 10.0, nan, 10.0,
        10.0, 10.0, nan, 10.0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
>>> np.where(np.isnan(X), X, 10)
array([[10., 10., nan, 10., 10., 10., nan, 10.]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get an array of `True`/`False` for `nan` location using `np.isnan`, invert it, and use it to replace all other values with 10.0

```
indices = np.isnan(X)
X[~indices] = 10.0
print(X) # [[10. 10. nan 10. 10. 10. nan 10.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner, in-place for `x`

```py
np.place(x, np.invert(np.isnan(x)), 10.0)
```